# Simple Injector spontaneously failing to inject for ASP.NET App deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am facing an issue with Dependency Injection (Simple Injector), but it only seems to occur when the application is deployed to a server running IIS, and only after it has been running for some time.  Based on the below StackTrace, it seems that there is a NullReference Exception that occurs during dependency injection.

**The interesting part is that if I restart the IIS Application, the application seems to continue working for some time.  At a later point, presuming that no one has accessed the website, the following StackTrace is displayed:**

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   DevOps.Data.DevOpsDbConnectionLoader.GetObjectInstanceInternal(Assembly
>   dbAssembly, String objectTypeName, Boolean isStatic) +16
>   DevOps.Data.DevOpsDbConnectionLoader.GetEntityDbProviderServices()
>   +156    NWatch.NWatchDbConfiguration..ctor(DevOpsDbConnectionLoader loader) +239    NWatch.NWatchEntityApplication.Init() +429
>   BranchCircuits_Web.MvcApplication.RegisterTypes(Container container)
>   +298    BranchCircuits_Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +299
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +12601949
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +475
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +12618996
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12458613

**Below is the Global.asax contents that is in charge for the dependency injection.**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    var webApiContainer = new Container();
    webApiContainer.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();
    RegisterTypes(webApiContainer);
    webApiContainer.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    webApiContainer.Verify();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(webApiContainer);
}

private void RegisterTypes(Container container)
{
    var virtualPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath.Substring(1);
    string baseName = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(virtualPath)) {
        baseName = HostingEnvironment.SiteName + "_" + virtualPath;
    } else {
        baseName = HostingEnvironment.SiteName;
    }

    var nWatchApp = new NWatchEntityApplication(GetNWatchConfig());
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new DevOps.Diagnostics.DevOpsLogTraceListener(baseName));
    container.RegisterSingleton<INWatchApplication>(nWatchApp);
    container.Register<NWatchDbContext>(() => nWatchApp.GetDbContext(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
}

private INWatchConfiguration GetNWatchConfig()
{
    Configuration rootConfig =
        System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
    return new NWatchSystemConfiguration(rootConfig);
}
```

Has anyone experienced this when deploying to IIS?  What is the root cause, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Why exactly do you expect Simple Injector to be involved in this? There are no Simple Injector calls in your stack trace. The stack trace indicates that the exception occurs when the application starts (or is restarted after IIS recycled it). Besides, I would say that the stack trace should give you a clear hint where to look for errors. Your custom `DevOps.Data.DevOpsDbConnectionLoader.GetObjectInstanceInternal` method probably lacks the proper null checks (you should throw an `ArgumentNullException` instead). Probably some calls up the call stack pass on a `null` reference to that method.

Comment: @Steven, the part I am having trouble understanding is why when IIS has to spin up the application again, it wouldn't be following the same logic and getting all the dependencies successfully, just like it was able to do when the application was first deployed.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know what you're missing, but since the application throws in your own code, it should beeasy to add the proper guard clauses, throw exceptions with the proper information for you to diagnose your issue.